# Number and Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

```
var a=new Number(6);

var b=new Object(6);
a===b;  //false
```

I just do not understand why a===b return false. It has same type and come from same instance.

Comment: Read the doc about `===` and `==`

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Those are objects you cannot compare by value . The objects are compared by their reference .

```
var a=new Number(6);

var b=new Object(6);

var c=new Number(6);

var d = a;

a === b;  //false
a == c; // false
b == c;//false
a == d;//true
```

Those are primitives any you can compare by value . Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value.

```
var a= Number(6);
var b= Number(6);
a == b //true
a === b //true
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS or whatever,

== chracters control for value. For example;

```
var a = "1";
var b = 1;

a == b: return true
```

=== chracters control value and type. For example;

```
a === b: return false
```